# How to get particular key value from a JSON data and filtered duplicate and pushed an array in angular 6 without for loop?

Tags: angular

JSON data looks like below:

```
data = [
      { position: 'Active', name: 'name1', email: 'mail1@mail.com', status: 'Yes' },
      { position: 'Pending', name: 'name2', email: 'mail2@mail.com', status: 'No' },
      { position: 'Issued', name: 'name3', email: 'mail3@mail.com', status: 'Yes' },
      { position: 'Active', name: 'name4', email: 'mail4@mail.com', status: 'No' },
      { position: 'Pending', name: 'name5', email: 'mail5@mail.com', status: 'Yes' },
      { position: 'Pending', name: 'name6', email: 'mail6@mail.com', status: 'No' },
      { position: 'Active', name: 'name7', email: 'mail7@mail.com', status: 'Yes' },
      { position: 'Pending', name: 'name8', email: 'mail8@mail.com', status: 'No' },
      { position: 'Issued', name: 'name9', email: 'mail9@mail.com', status: 'Yes' },
      { position: 'Active', name: 'name10', email: 'mail10@mail.com', status: 'No' },
    ];
```

I want to "position" status will be pushed in an array.

example:

```
status = ['Active', 'Pending', 'Issued']
```

How can I achieve this without for loop in angular.

Thanks

Comment: Have updated answer with forloop and without forloop

Comment: @imjayabal please see the one liner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set` to get unique values from an array. 
 Use `Array.map` function to get the only array of positions.
 Lastly, convert the `Set` to `Array` using spread operator as `[...yourSet]`

```
   [...new Set(this.data.map(e=>e.position))]
```

[image]

Comment: When updating the code I was getting an error in angular "Type 'Set<string>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.". So I modify like this [...Array.from(new Set(data.map(res => res.Status)))]. Now working fine

Comment: @imjayabal please upvote the answer as well. Thank you.

Comment: `compiler option '--downlevelIteration'` is a new learning, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You would basically do this.

```
const status = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc.find(item => item === curr.position) 
   ? acc
   : [...acc, curr.position]
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by

```
   status = data.map((t) => { return t.position });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you specially asked for the solution without for loop but I would do like this:

```
result: any = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
   var index = this.result.indexOf(this.data[i].position);
   if (index == -1) {
       this.result.push(this.data[i].position);
   }
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vewqcf-3jwuem)

> EDIT:

Without for loop (Have searched and found one useful example [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-array-distinct-5edc93501dc4)):

```
this.result = this.data.map(x => x.position);
var expectedOutput = this.result.filter(this.getUnique))
```

Write one function:

```
getUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Result:

```
["Active","Pending","Issued"]
```

[`StackBlitz Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vewqcf-3jwuem)